# Hotelbeds API Availability Exception java.lang.StackOverflowError Without Hotelbeds SDK PHP

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

Trying to get hotel availability from Hotelbeds API and sometimes return Internal Server Error response :

(8 failed attempts from 20 request)

### Request URL

https://api.test.hotelbeds.com/hotel-api/1.0/hotels

### Request Body

https://pastebin.com/C3z2BA9Z

```
{"sourceMarket":"ID","stay":{"checkIn":"2018-08-17","checkOut":"2018-08-18"},"occupancies":[{"rooms":1,"adults":1,"children":0}],"hotels":{"hotel":[24196,24197,24199,24200,24202,24203,24204,24216,24217,24218,24219,24220,24221,24222,24225,24226,24227,24228,24229,24230,24340,24341,24399,24400,24401,24403,24405,24406,24407,24408,24409,24410,24411,24412,24413,24421,24422,24423,25036,25558,25559,25561,26844,26845,26846,26848,26849,53588,53589,53590,53591,53592,53594,53595,61826,61827,61829,61830,71803,71804,71807,71808,71809,71813,71815,71816,71859,71860,71863,71864,71865,71866,71867,71869,71871,71872,71875,71876,71877,71880,71881,74640,74641,75362,79813,79814,79815,79817,79818,79819,79820,79821,79822,79824,79825,79827,79828,79978,79979,79980,79981,79982,79983,79984,79985,79986,79987,80910,80918,80990,81016,81018,83482,83483,83856,83857,83859,83860,84439,84440,84441,84442,84443,84444,84445,84446,84447,92159,92160,92161,92162,92163,92165,92166,92167,92772,92773,92925,92926,92930,93195,93198,93199,93200,93203,93204,93233,93295,93297,93761,93766,93767,93768,93769,93770,94035,94115,94116,94117,94443,94470,94874,94875,95101,95614,95679,95977,95978,96173,96174,96175,96176,96178,96180,96182,96183,96184,96185,96187,96188,96189,96334,96335,96336,96337,96339,96340,96341,96343,96344,96356,96357,96358,96359,96360,96361,96365,96367,96369,96373,96374,96375,96378,96417,96418,96420,96421,96422,96423,96431,96432,96433,96434,96511,96515,96517,96518,96576,96579,96582,96588,96592,96593,96598,96600,96603,96605,96606,96607,96608,96609,96610,96611,96612,96616,96619,96621,96625,96628,96632,96633,96636,96637,96638,96641,96642,96644,96645,96651,96652,96653,96655,96658,96661,96662,96663,96664,96666,96667,96855,96883,96884,96894,96895,96899,96900,96901,96913,96914,96915,96916,96933,96934,96935,96940,96942,96955,97032,97450,97452,97454,97461,97462,97463,97476,97478,97479,98095,98602,98604,98605,98614,98616,98617,98619,98620,98621,98654,98656,98674,98675,98676,100398,100765,101255,101965,102234,102235,103062,103474,103797,103821,104194,104319,104580,104640,104644,104944,105114,105401,105555,105561,106099,106447,106643,106651,106652,106750,107183,108005,108696,109316,109403,109458,109514,110254,110360,110373,110628,110629,110630,111597,111757,111826,111852,111853,112227,112639,112640,113165,113167,113479,113480,113491,113492,113846,114593,114904,114905,114933,114934,115626,115627,115630,115632,115870,115913,116253,116254,117242,117993,118357,119798,120205,120207,120215,120602,120817,120957,121304,121318,121320,121322,121486,122047,122099,122190,122244,122391,122392,122638,122704,122931,123196,123281,123322,123804,123932,124000,124039,124041,124152,124153,124467,124753,125537,125549,126009,126010,126245,126247,126529,126678,126679,128333,128334,128335,128336,128341,128345,128383,128714,128715,128773,128845,131438,131457,131458,131460,131582,131786,131789,131791,131825,131826,131849,131850,131852,132429,132457,132458,132459,132460,132501,134083,134084,134290,134771,134777,135087,135088,135089,135101,135103,135105,135107,135115,135116,135117,135118,135159,135160,135163,135264,135265,135266,135267,135268,135867,136372,136373,136378,136379,136787,137501,137502,137503,139337,140625,141282,141283,141463,141535,142052,142054,142150,142660,142937,143698,143699,143700,143701,143702,144018,145225,145418,145500,145570,146259,146638,146708,146709,146904,146905,147036,147047,147212,147282,147283,147339,147357,147368,147369,147408,147409,147410,147562,147563,147564,147735,148365,148366,148611,148659,148763,150459,150460,150725,150726,150815,150983,150984,150985,150986,150987,150988,151343,151502,151841,151842,151940,152704,152705,152706,152708,152929,153262,153406,153424,153427,153428,153564,153765,153862,153986,154171,154320,154322,155557,155703,156038,156293,156576,156577,156578,156614,156618,156691,156969,156986,157012,157357,157417,158763,160751,160793,161057,161162,161233,161438,161579,161640,162252,162383,162947,163006,164421,164801,168919,168925,169998,171161,172456,173249,173437,173523,173524,173588,174450,175186,175187,175744,175821,176472,176771,176779,177087,177256,177912,178470,179158,179635,180127,180187,180429,180529,180530,181793,182452,182456,183250,183251,183902,183903,184048,184070,184229,184324,184327,184328,184329,184698,185029,185197,185358,185359,185724,186288,186291,186330,186773,186774,186806,187277,187493,187689,187810,188241,188242,188327,188451,188452,188694,188695,188993,189141,189472,189771,190369,190825,191452,191777,191778,191851,192260,192261,192262,192379,192380,192521,192561,194570,195504,195800,195846,196121,196595,196697,197378,198002,198170,198171,198176,198321,198917,199266,208691,208971,208997,209000,209275,209277,209279,211259,212469,212470,214638,215271,215302,215321,215334,215478,215481,215518,215574,215575,215576,215577,215608,216267,216481,216500,216501,216658,216739,216834,216836,216837,216984,217177,217611,217612,217613,217738,217781,217843,218064,218198,218341,218478,218480,218579,218580,218585,218586,218670,218671,221066,221658,221660,221663,221975,222063,222064,222110,222111,222219,222266,222336,222449,222452,222454,222456,222463,222644,222645,222994,223016,223243,223476,223674,223713,224311,224537,225945,226139,226140,226285,226288,226746,230365,231516,231517,231521,231529,231533,231534,231539,231544,233144,233145,233146,233167,233168,233214,233217,233232,233237,233238,233284,233285,233289,233290,233291,233309,233311,233314,233315,233316,233317,233318,233319,233346,233353,234391,234392,234394,234395,234396,234401,234403,234406,234407,234408,234411,234413,234414,234415,234421,234427,234428,234429,234434,234442,234464,234465,234468,234470,234474,234475,234476,234478,234481,234486,234487,234488,234492,234497,234499,234502,234503,234529,234532,234534,234535,234537,234538,234540,234543,234545,234546,234547,234549,234551,234553,234555,234558,234559,234565,234566,234568,234572,234575,234579,234582,234583,234587,234588,234591,234592,234593,234594,234595,234597,234600,234602,234603,234624,234627,234628,234630,234632,234667,235619,235620,235623,235624,235636,235645,235649,235650,235651,235655,235656,235658,235660,235661,235663,235671,235673,235675,235676,235679,235683,235684,235689,235691,235692,235696,235698,235701,235703,235705,235709,235710,235712,235714,235715,235721,235722,235723,235724,235733,235738,235741,235742,235845,236796,236974,236983,236985,236991,236997,237001,237005,237006,237010,237014,237015,237018,237019,237025,237027,237028,237029,237030,237033,237035,237048,237059,237062,237063,237073,237077,237083,237085,237090,237091,237095,237096,237102,237103,237124,237130,237131,237132,253743,253749,253757,253763,253764,253766,253767,253768,253771,253772,253775,253783,253790,253791,253798,253807,253810,253812,253819,253829,253830,253838,253847,253848,253858,253871,253890,253894,253899,253908,253916,254498,254499,254558,254670,254690,254691,254824,254945,254966,255017,255028,255040,255161,255232,255409,255494,255499,255603,255606,255607,255653,255656,255669,256337,256343,256404,256500,256530,256542,256656,256669,256885,256985,257129,257162,257282,261525,261541,261581,261692,261726,261739,261749,261778,261790,261848,261941,261944,261957,262048,262096,262123,262162,262243,262256,262277,262328,262345,262451,270823,270863,270881,271014,271109,271131,271148,271221,271304,271356,271421,271445,271487,271663,271735,271754,271808,272010,272158,272265,272289,272595,272642,272643,272777,272905,273047,273068,273114,273210,273297,273320,273324,273334,273638,273709,273758,273894,273964,274113,274142,274182,274252,274344,274475,274546,274576,274624,274800,274998,275099,275423,275497,275522,275704,275835,276092,276106,276196,276342,276385,276480,276553,276631,276818,276966,276988,277078,277358,277414,277704,277794,277909,277945,278122,278126,278157,278174,278295,278327,278391,278585,357320,357327,357408,357417,357420,357610,357665,357826,357827,357848,357902,357908,357954,357966,358004,358018,358030,358082,358083,358089,358093,358114,358160,358179,358218,361307,361308,361309,361424,361641,361815,361978,362767,363875,363876,363917,364012,364340,364470,364742,365275,365427,365429,365430,365598,365605,365606,365607,366100,366599,366711,367097,367203,367556,367637,367728,368006,368603,368738,368744,368755,368774,368836,368917,368920,368921,369061,369062,369170,369272,369340,369342,369343,369344,369345,369421,369422,369424,369426,369427,369428,369429,369434,369435,369437,369439,369440,369483,369485,369564,369839,369843,369846,370327]},"filter":{"paymentType":"AT_WEB"}}
```

### Response Body

```
{
  "timestamp": 1534133396201,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "java.lang.StackOverflowError",
  "message": "Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError",
  "path": "/1.0/hotels"
}
```

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: If you get this error without their SDK but not with it, why not just use it? Also, have you contacted the developers/support for the API? You should also always include all the relevant code. When using API's, there are usually some headers etc that needs to be sent (which the developers/manual usually can help you with) in the request. I would probably contact the developers either way, since you get a stack overflow error from the server (which means somethings not right on their side).

Comment: I have contacted the support for API,but it still hasn't been answered. I agree with you about "somethings not right on their side", so we think there is no need to refactor our code using SDK. Maybe someone in here have experienced this too.

Comment: It's more likely that they will tell you to use their sdk though, since it works with it (and I would agree with them). If they do changes in the API, they will probably update the SDK to match and you won't need to do a lot of extra work. For maintinance purposes, it would probably be better to use it straight away.

Comment: I have try to use Hotelbeds API SDK PHP, the result is same, sometime it returns same error

Answer (score 0):

For someone that may experience this issue, I suggest to break hotel list to max. 500 hotels / request. It solve our issue